# How to catch the value in a td element with jquery and change another td elements background color based on the caught td's value?

Tags: jquery, html

I've spent some time today looking at examples to iterate through a table and its rows with JQuery, after a lot of trial an error I was able to do it. But I am running into an issue trying to get a value from td element, so I can change to color of another td element.
I have a repeater bound to a datatable. The markup looks like this..

```
<div>
<table id="Table">
    <tr>
        <th>Global Group
        </th>
        <th>Option ID
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr align="left">
                    <td id="header">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblOptionName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("GlobalGroup_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="level"><%#Eval("GlobalGroup_Level")%></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Originally I had a label in the td class=level, and I was able to highlight what I wanted in the OnItemDataBound event. But I want to do it with JQuery instead.

This is what I came up with...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Table tr").each(function () {
            var cell = $(this).find("td.level").text();
            if (cell == "0") $("#header").css('background-color', 'purple');
        });
    })
```

This the table data

```
Global Group     Option ID
floor                1
hardwood             1
parkay               1
handle               0
brass                1
stainless            1
nickel               1
door                 0
hardwood             1
steel                1
screen               1
```

etc...
What I been trying to do is everytime Option ID is a 0, I want to have a background color to its matching Global Group... I.E handle's Option ID is 0, so the td element that has handle in it should have its background color changed and so on.

What the code is doing is only adding a background color to the very first td element under Global Group but as you can see that the Option ID for floor is a 1 and shouldn't have a background color.

So can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: might be able to understand better if you created a fiddle. but the fact that you are using an ID for the selector `#header` could be a problem if you want an action to happen on more than one element.

Comment: you need to use this instead $(this).find("#header").css('background-color', 'purple');

Comment: @BillPull, thanks, I will keep that in mind about the header as an ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the background of the `header` element which is in the same `tr` so as the current `level` element so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Table tr").each(function () {
        var cell = $(this).find("td.level").text();
        if (cell == "0") {
            $(this).find(".header").css('background-color', 'purple');
        }
    });
})
```

Also since ID of an element must be unique, use `header` as a class

```
<tr align="left">
    <td class="header">
        <asp:Label ID="lblOptionName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("GlobalGroup_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td class="level">
        <%#Eval( "GlobalGroup_Level")%>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In your code, since you are using the id selector to find the header element, it will always return the first element with the ID `header`

Comment: That worked perfectly. I'll accept as answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

BillPull is right that making your header an ID isnt good practice. IDs should only occur once on a page, try making it a class

OR

You can make use of jquery's .siblings(). Your code should read something similar to this:

```
    var cell = $(this).find("td.level");
    if (cell.text() == "0") {
        cell.siblings('td').css('background-color', 'purple');
    }
```

Example: [JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwzzbdq2/)

Comment: Not exactly sure if they're the best practice but in isolated situations they can be useful. I find they work very well in tables.